# How to create right outerjoin in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA, Hibernate, MySQL.

I have two tables Upload, UploadRating. Each upload can have multiple ratings in UploadRating table i.e. OneToMany. UploadRating has an attribute user which defines the user who has rated the upload.

Now I want to know all the Uploads for which UploadRating is not present for a user. 
so query is something like :

```
from Upload up,  UploadRating  ur where ur.upload=up and ur.user != :usrId
```

I know there is a flaw in above query. We need to use outer join in this case. Can some one help me the query please.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  Upload up 
where 
  not exists (select * from UploadRating ur where ur.upload_id=up.id and ur.user = :usrId)
```

assuming that `upload_id` is the upload rating column containing the unique id of each upload.

The equivalent SQL using a join would be something like this:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  Upload up 
  left outer join UploadRating ur on ur.upload_id=up.id
where 
  (ur.user <> :usrId) or (ur.user is null)
```

Comment: If I am trying this I am getting following exception:org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 72 [from com.kids.domain.Upload as up left outer join  UploadRating  as ur on ur.upload_id=up.id  where  ur.subCont=:subCont and ur.user != :usrId and moderated=true and semiFinalUpload = :semiFinalUp  order by  :orderBy]

Comment: No idea - that `on` is correct SQL, I don't know why Hibernate would not like it (note also that I fixed a mistake in the `where` condition)

Comment: I was trying your first option too of "not exists". But its returning all rows. The column common in both tables is upload; i.e. UploadRating.uploadId = Upload.id

Comment: ...just realized: what you are asking for is the HQL query, not the SQL one - correct?

Comment: Yes I want to use HQL because that will give me the object of Upload directly. If I use native SQL; it would return columns of both tables and it might get messy to create Object only of Upload

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with HQL - I don't know it enough